# perl hashref/ perl syntax

Tags: perl, hash, dbi

A variation of this code passed by today (written by a perl coder), and it is confusing:

```
   my $k = {3,5,6,8};
   my $y = {%$k};
```

Why? What does that do? That seems to be the same thing as this:

```
   my $y = $k;
```

The context is in a call using dbi module:

```
               while (my $x = $db->fetchrow_hashref )
               {  $y{something} = {%$x};  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that it's **cloning** the data structure without referencing the same memory.

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $h={'a'=>1,'b'=>2};
my $exact_copy=$h; #$exact_copy references the same memory as $h
$h->{b}++; #$h maps b to 3

print Dumper($exact_copy) . "\n"; #a=>1,b=>3

my $clone={%$h}; #We dereference $h and then make a new reference
$h->{a}++; #h now maps a to 2

print Dumper($clone) . "\n"; #a=>1,b=>3 so this clone doesn't shadow $h
```

Incidentally, manually initialising a hash by using all commas (as in `my $k = {3,5,6,8}`) is very, very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

`{ }`, in this case, is the hash constructor. It creates a new hash and returns a reference to it. So

Compare

```
my $k = { a => 4 };
my $y = $k;
$k->{a} = 5;
print $y->{a};   # 5
```

with

```
my $k = { a => 4 };
my $y = { %$k };
$k->{a} = 5;
print $y->{a};   # 4
```

Comment: @Jack Maney: if you're going to be that picky, then `{ }` is indeed a *hash constructor*, specifically of an anonymous hash. A hash reference doesn't need constructing and can't exist separately from a hash. The second sentence says it *creates a new hash* and you don't take issue with that.